# Recreate an array of m nonincreasing integers between 1-n in O(n) time with at most ⌈log n⌉ guesses per index & directional responses to wrong guesses

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, binary-search

In a game, your objective is to guess a number from the range 1 to n. You are allowed to make a maximum of ⌈log n⌉ guesses per round. Over the course of m rounds (where m < n), you record the correct answers in an array M[i], with i starting from 1 to m. Initially, designing an algorithm that runs in O(m*log(n)) time is straightforward.
However, a new condition has been introduced: M[i] ≤ M[j] for all i > j, which means the answers are in descending order. The task is to find an algorithm that operates in O(n) time, given this modified condition.

Based on the condition M[i] ≤ M[j] for all i > j, I can narrow down the range between 1 to n. But in the worst case, I still cannot get O(n).
Also, you cannot brutal force to guess the numbers, there is a limit on it.

Some clarifications:
1.When you guess, you are told it's too large or too small. (it's a classic binary search question)
2.The answers are in a descending order.
3.The limit of guessing times in each round is ⌈log n⌉, not log(n) + 1, sorry for my mistakes in the previous statement.

Let me give an example, hope this helps.

- Let's play a game, you need to guess an integer from 1 to 100 (n = 100).
- You need to play it 10 rounds (m = 10).
- In each round, you have ⌈log n⌉ guesses. I will tell you if your answer is too big or too small.
- The answer in next round is always equal to or less than previous round. Such as: {98,88,76,76,76,74,65,43,43,42}

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you guess, are you just told whether or not you're correct, or are you told whether your wrong guess is too large or too small?

Comment: Are the answers in a _descending_ order, or are they in a _non-ascending_ order?

Comment: If you are still limited to log_2(n)+1 guesses in each round, then I don't think this is possible.  If you aren't then it's easy -- always guess the highest possible answer.

Comment: I don't think the question is well formed. If `m` is part of the input, there must be `m` in your time, since just reading that input takes time `log(m)`. In this case, you even have to write the `m` answers, so you need time at least `O(n+m)`

Comment: When you guess, you are told it's too large or too small.

Comment: Well, I'll have to check my answer with the revised question. @mouse -- can you confirm that the logarithms are base 2?

Comment: Yes, Dave, log2 n. Thanks for your effort! Let me read your detailed answer and learn from it.

Comment: @mouse I think my approach still works. The worst case is when n is a power of 2, say n = 2^k. Then our first guess is 2^k - k + 1. If the answer is larger then we're fine. If it's smaller then we have k-1 steps to find the value in the range [1, 2^k - k] via binary search. I think but need to prove or look up, that this is always possible.

Comment: @Dave I'm thinking, according to your solution,  If the answer is smaller then we have k-1 steps to find the value in the range [1, 2^k - k] via binary search(I agree!), which means we may need to perform a binary search in every single round to get a correct answer in the worst case. Then, the time complexity is O(log n), totally still be O(m*log n). You can say n is shrinking I guess. What do you think?

Comment: @mouse I need to get the kiddos fed & to bed; will try to get to this tonight. Basically as long as it takes at most r steps to guess a value at least r below the prior value, we're on track for solving this in O(n) time. I believe all that is true & my algorithm works, but I can't focus on it for a few hours.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. Please don't feel rushed; I genuinely appreciate your assistance, and I'm quite pleased to have your support.

Comment: @mouse I rewrote my answer based on your clarifications. Please let me know if anything needs further explanation.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for your help, I’m currently in school, I will have a thorough look into your solution and get  back to you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inputs:**

- n: an integer
- M: a nonincreasing array of integers in the range 1-n, with 1 as the first index. |M| = m < n.

**Goal:** recreate M in sequence by making at most ⌈log n⌉ guesses per index, with a running time of O(n). I.e. we can't directly access M, but just guess a value of the first undetermined index and learn whether our guess is correct, or too big, or too small.

**Notation:**

- Let k = ⌈log n⌉, our max guesses per index.
- Let M' be the output array. Unlike the input array, for convenience this will be zero-indexed, with M'[0] = n. Our goal will be to have M'[i] = M[i] for 1 <= i <= n.

**Procedure to determine M[i] given M[i-1]:**

- guess 1: M[i-1] - k + 1
- case 1: If our first guess is correct, we're done.
- case 2: if our first guess is too small, the correct answer is one of the k-1 values between M[i-1] and M[i-1] - k + 2 inclusive. We will guess these in descending order.
- case 3: if our first guess is too large, the correct answer is between 1 and M[i-1] - k inclusive. We use binary search to determine the correct answer in at most k-1 additional steps, for a total of k.

**First Constraint Analysis:** guess each number in at most k = ⌈log n⌉ steps.

case 1 steps: 1

case 2 steps: M[i] - M[i-1] + 1 <= k

case 3: Binary search will take at most ⌈log n⌉ - 1 steps in the range 1 to n - ⌈log n⌉. Given that, this takes at most k steps (the initial guess, plus at most k-1 for binary search).

So this satisfies the first constraint, that each number is guessed in at most k steps.

**Second Constraint Analysis:** The algorithm should be O(n).

Let's say G[i] is the number of guesses we make to determine M[i]. Note that for all three cases, G[i] <= M[i-1] - M[i] + 1. In other words, if successive values of M differ by r, we will determine the latter value in at most r+1 guesses (never more than k, but we don't need that fact for this portion).

But the cumulative difference across all of M is at most n-1, and |M| < n, so the total number of guesses must be <= (n-1) + |M| < (n-1) + n = 2n-1 = O(n).

Comment: Thank you, Dave! This algorithm is absolutely fantastic. Your creative approach and careful analysis have truly impressed me. It's a brilliant solution that elegantly solves a challenging problem. I've realized that you ingeniously found a way to circumvent the log n guess limit by utilizing the fact that the answers are in descending order. Your approach is exceptionally clever!